# Method mocked remains for other tests as well

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am writing JUnits for my Spring controller. In one of the cases, I am testing the `Exception` `catch`ed within the controller. I have mocked the service to throw a RuntimeException. Other test checks the successful output.

Individually both tests work, but when I execute both together, if the first test executes first, then the second test too throw RuntimeException. Is there anything that I need to deregister the mocked method?

(Please ignore the syntax)

```
class UserController {
  @Autowired
  UserService service;

  @RequestMapping("...")
  public ResponseEntity getUser(){
     try{
        User user = service.getUserAttributes();
        return new ResponseEntity(user, HttpStatus.OK);
     }
     catch(Exception e){
        return new ResponseEntity("Eror", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
     }
  }  
}


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestConfig.class)
public class UserControllerDocumentation {
  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
  private RestDocumentationResultHandler document;
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Rule
  public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

  @Autowired
  UserService userService;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    this.document = document("{method-name}", preprocessRequest(prettyPrint()),
                preprocessResponse(prettyPrint()));
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
        .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation)).alwaysDo(document)
        .build();
  }


 @Test
  public void textError() throws Exception {
    when(userService.getUserAttributes(anyInt())).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user/xxx")
            .accept("application/xml"))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }

  @Test
  public void textUser() throws Exception {
    when(userService.getUserAttributes(anyInt())).thenReturn(mockUserObj);
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user/10")
            .accept("application/xml"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I need to return something for the mocked method even after throwing an exception. Added `thenReturn(null)` after `thenThrow`

```
 @Test
  public void textError() throws Exception {
    when(userService.getUserAttributes(anyInt())).thenThrow(new RuntimeException()).thenReturn(null);
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/user/xxx")
            .accept("application/xml"))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how @Autowired works, but obviously: your class has one instance of `userService`; and your textError() testcase configures that to throw an exception. And when your second test runs, that "behavior specification" is still in place and throws on you.

Thus, I see two options:

a) you use your "after" or "before" methods to reset the userService

b) each test method gets its own userService

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reset mocked object before you run each test.
You can do it using reset method.

Here are more details
http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17

To run this before each class you can use `@Before` annotation.